# cannot find faces context in jsf

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jboss

I am trying to create a simple program on JSF.I deployed it on JBOSS 5 server.But when i try to run it it throws these exception.

> **type** Exception report
>
> **message**  description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented
>   it from fulfilling this request.
>
> **exception** org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot
>   find FacesContext
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:515)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>     org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
>
> **root cause**
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find FacesContext
>     javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.getFacesContext(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1855)
>     javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.setJspId(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1672)
>     org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(index_jsp.java:90)
>     org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:67)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>     org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)

Comment: Can you please post your code? and your folder structure too. What libraries are you adding in your `WEB-INF/lib`?

Answer (score 3):

This exception will be thrown when the request URL as appears in the browser's address bar does not match the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet` as definied in webapp's `web.xml`. If the `FacesServlet` is not invoked, then the `FacesContext` will not be created and then the JSF components in your JSP page will throw this exception.

If the URL pattern is for example

```
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
```

then you should be opening the page by using `index.jsf` in browser address bar instead of `index.jsp`.