# cannot load jsp page

Tags: java, jsf

**I am trying to create a simple JSF project but index.jsp page doesnot open and throws exception**

> javax.faces.FacesException: An exception occurred processing JSP page
>   /index.jsp at line 5
>
> 2: <%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%> 3: <%@
>   taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%> 4:  5:  6:  7:
>    8:
>
> **Stacktrace:**
>
> > org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:347)
> >     org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.buildView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:486) org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:337)
>
> org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
>
> org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:140)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:187)   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet.service(MyFacesServlet.java:103)
>
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:828)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
>   JSP page /index.jsp at line 5
>
> 2: <%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%> 3: <%@
>   taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%> 4:  5:  6:  7:
>    8:
>
> Stacktrace:   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:498)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:444)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:382)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:310)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:341)
>     ... 26 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find
>   FacesContext  at
>   javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.getFacesContext(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1855)
>     at
>   javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.setJspId(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1672)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(index_jsp.java:87)
>     at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:64)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
>     ... 36 more

**i thought it was an server error but when i tried to access server from browser.it works fine.and i ve checked out for libraries of JSF and it is also included under jboss server
can some please help me...**

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<f:view>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h:outputLabel value="i am here!!!!!!"></h:outputLabel>
</body>
</html>
</f:view>
```

i cant upload image of folder strucure due to reputation level..

**lib folder doesnot contain any libraries rather it is in libraries inside javaResources:src folder..**

Comment: Can you please post your code? and folder structure too. What libraries are you adding in your WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: Try changing the jar version and try again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot find faces context in jsf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009298/cannot-find-faces-context-in-jsf)

Comment: Please do not repost the same problem/question multiple times. In future questions please use code button to format exceptions/stacktraces, not the quote button.